# How to solve an exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function

$8^X + 7 (2^{X+1}) = 7 (4^X) + 8$

$2^{3X} + 7 (2^{X+1}) = 7 (2^{2X}) + 2^3$

$3X = 3$

$X =1$

OR

$X+1 = 2X$

$X=1$

BUT answer $X = 0$, or $1$ or $2$ ????

Comment: What did you do? Also LaTeX it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you compare $2^{3X}$ with $2^3$ to get $3X=3$ and compare $2^{X+1}$ with $2^{2X}$ to get $X+1=2X$, but you cannot do this in general.

Let $t=2^X$. Then, noting that 
$$2^{3X}=(2^X)^3=t^3,\ 7\cdot 2^{X+1}=7\cdot 2\cdot 2^X=14t,\ 2^{2X}=(2^X)^2=t^2,$$we have
$$t^3-7t^2+14t-8=0\Rightarrow (t-1)(t-2)(t-4)=0\Rightarrow X=0,1,2.$$

Comment: how to convert t3−7t2+14t−8 to (t−1)(t−2)(t−4)

Comment: @sekling: Do you know [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)?

Comment: Great, got it, THANKS

Comment: @sekling: You are welcome. By the way, I added a bit. Take a look.